# How to retrieve specific data about user?

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to create a system where ads will be hidden if a user clicks any ad more than once. When they go on to my site, it'll check if their ip is in the database, if not then their ip will be stored. Next, it'll check to see how many clicks they've had so far, if it exceeds 1 ads will be hidden. This is the part i'm struggling with right now. I've commented out what I want to happen in the code below. Also, I have 4 columns in my table: id, ip, count (# of clicks), and datetime. I am using mysqli, and I just want to know how do I retrieve the number of clicks a user has based on their ip. Here is an example of what the Stats table looks like: id: 1    ip: xx.xx.xx.xx    count: 0    creation: datetime

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))  
{
   $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
}
elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   
{
   $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}
else
{
   $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
}
$query = "SELECT count(*) FROM Stats WHERE ip = '$ip'";
$result = $db->query($query); 
if($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    //if user's click count > 1
    hide ads
    else
    display ads         
}
else {
   $insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO Stats(ip, created) VALUES (?, NOW())"); 
   $insert->bind_param('s', $ip);
   $insert->execute();
   $insert->close();
}
```

Comment: I wonder if I can add Http_x_forwarded_for...

Comment: Wouldn't you just select the column called `count`..? since `count(*)` is the amount of rows returned...not the actual times the user has clicked...

Comment: @Darren Well i'm using count(*) just for the sake of checking if the user's ip is new or not, if it is new i'll add it in the database. I want to check the count number for that particular user, if the count number exceeds 1 then ads are hidden

Comment: please update your question with raw data of table `Stats`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an alias for your aggregate using the `AS` keyword in order to access it from `fetch_assoc`.

```
$query = "SELECT count(*) AS total FROM Stats WHERE ip = '$ip'";    

if ($result = $db->query($query)) {

$data = $result->fetch_assoc();

    if($data['total']>1){
        // This user already clicked on at least one AD. Don't show ADS.     
    }else{
        // This user haven't clicked an AD yet. Show ADS.
    }
}
```

Replace

```
if($result->num_rows > 0)
```

with

```
if($data['total']>1)
```

as it's not needed anymore. Thank you @Shehary for pointing that out.

Comment: There is one more reason you need to add in your answer that The `$result->num_rows` is useless. When you use `SELECT COUNT(*)` in query, my upvote :)

Comment: Just to be sure, when getting the count number I just say:

if($data["count"] > 1)
{
        //remove ads
}
else{
//don't remove ads
}
?

Comment: @JoSmo Don't worry, I will soon ;) I just have a few more questions. Is total is referencing the count column? Also, what if the ip is not in the database, do I just create it under the else statement you posted saying (This user hasn't clicked any ads. Show ads)?

Comment: "Is total is referencing the count column?" Yes.

Comment: If the ip is not in the database, then the `total` will be 0. This way the code in the `else` code block will be executed which is `// This user haven't clicked an AD yet. Show ADS.`

Comment: What if the ip is in the database, but they haven't clicked any ads? Do I use my original code for the ip part, and add your code for the count part?

Comment: If you want to restart it every day, add `AND date >= today` at the end of `WHERE`.

Comment: Will that only restart the count column each day?

Comment: Yes. It will count only for that day.

Comment: @JoSmo What if the ip is in the database, but they haven't clicked any ads? Do I use my original code for the ip part, and add your code for the count part?

Comment: How would the IP be in the database if the user didn't click on ads? I though that the IP gets inserted only after a user clicks on an ad.

Comment: I wanted to track all i.p addresses, but you know what I think your process is better, no need for all the useless i.p addresses, I just want the ones that click the ads. So when total > 1, I then hide ads and input their ip and count number in the database?

Comment: Or create 2 tables, one for tracking ad clicks and one for tracking views. When `total > 1` you just hide the ads, you don't need to insert their IP again as it would be the same if the count would be 1 or 2 it's more than 0. You insert their IP only when they click on an ad.

Answer (score 0):

```
  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Stats WHERE ip = '$ip'") or die(mysql_error());    

  if (mysql_affected_rows()){
    // This user already clicked on at least one AD. Don't show ADS.     
  }
  else {
   // This user haven't clicked an AD yet. Show ADS.
  }
```